# Mongo Scala Driver: PullByFilter Based on Nested Field Value

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I have a model ***band*** that contains a list of ***tours***

```
Band:
{ 
  name: String,
  email: String,
  createdAt: String,
  tours: Tour[],
  ...
}
```

where a Tour is:

```
{
name: String,
region: String,
published: Boolean,
...
}
```

The goal is simply to create an end point that receives a Band Name and Tour Name deletes a tour based on this input.

The following works:

```
bandService.getBandByName(req.getParam("bandName")).flatMap{ b =>
  val tour = b.tours.filter(t => t.name == req.getParam("tourName")).head
  mongoDataBaseConnector.bands.findOneAndUpdate(
    equal("bandName", req.getParam("bandName")),
    pull("tours", tour)
  ).toFuture().flatMap(u => bandService.getBandByName(req.getParam("bandName")))
```

However, this requires me to first resolve the band by the name received first, filter, find the tour and pass in the ***exact*** object in to the **pull** I am trying to avoid this by using **pullByFilter** but can't seem to get this to work. Unfortunately couldn't find any examples of this function in the scala driver.

This is what I am trying:

```
mongoDataBaseConnector.bands.findOneAndUpdate(
      and(
        equal("bandName", req.getParam("bandName")),
        equal("tours.name", req.getParam("tourName"))),
      pullByFilter(and(
        equal("tours.$.name", req.getParam("tourName")),
        equal("tours.$.region", req.getParam("region"))
      ))
    ).toFuture().flatMap(u => bandService.getBandByName(req.getParam("bandName")))
```

this gives the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value' on server cluster0-shard-00-01-sqs4t.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1568589476, "i": 8}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1568589476, "i": 8}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "Qz/DqAdG11H8KRkW8gtvRAAE61Q=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "6710077417139994625"}}}}
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Is this even possible with this function?

Comment: Have you first tried the query in mongoshell? Before programmatically? To check query syntax/grammar?

Comment: @cchanted I am not sure what you mean. I believe pullByFilter is a function defined in the Java/Scala DSLs, I can't seem to find any reference to it in the shell docs. It likely evaluates to {..$filter(...), $pull(...)}. As I have mentioned in the post, I am able to get this to work using pull, granted I resolve the target object first (which I am trying to avoid). This asserts that the field names etc. are indeed correct. The problem is either in the DSL synthax I am using or the DSL function itself is not capable of evaluating this kind of query

Comment: DSL is just a way to write BSON, if it works in shell, then you are able to write the corresponding BSON

Comment: Yes I can just write the string query and execute but the question is if this can be achieved with any built in DSL functions. I am still not able to get pullByFilter to work so I am guessing it wasn't built for this purpose, the documentation is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've been working on a nearly identical problem all day.  What I have isn't great, but it's enough that I'm willing to accept it and hopefully someone will be able to make it into a more fully-formed solution.  Or at least I can save someone else some time.

`pullByFilter` only accepts one argument.  It seems that argument can be another `Bson` filter which is applied directly to each of the children, or a `BsonValue` that will be matched against.  Since none of the `Bson` filters step into the child documents, you have to create a `BsonValue`, specifically, a document.  I believe this should solve your problem:

```
mongoDataBaseConnector.bands.findOneAndUpdate(
      and(
        equal("bandName", req.getParam("bandName")),
        equal("tours.name", req.getParam("tourName"))),
      pullByFilter(BsonDocument().append("tours", BsonDocument()
          .append("name", req.getParam("tourName"))
          .append("region", req.getParam("region"))
      ))
    ).toFuture().flatMap(u => bandService.getBandByName(req.getParam("bandName")))
```

I would have liked to be able to switch back using `Bson` filters after getting to the inner document, but it seems that once you're in `BsonValue`s, you can't go back.

Edit: To help whoever comes after me: I think there should be a way to solve this more cleanly with `arrayFilters`, but I haven't yet found it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
 mongoDataBaseConnector.bands.findOneAndUpdate(
  and(
    equal("bandName", req.getParam("bandName")),
    equal("tours.name", req.getParam("tourName"))),
  pullByFilter(Filters.eq("tours", and(
    equal("name", req.getParam("tourName")),
    equal("region", req.getParam("region"))
  )))
).toFuture().flatMap(u => bandService.getBandByName(req.getParam("bandName")))
```